# Redundancy in inserting random number in database - angularjs asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I got a `foreach loop` in my `angularjs controller`

```
AccountController
angular.forEach($scope.accountList,function (account) {

      AccountService.insertNewAccount(account).then(function (msg)
           //some codes
      });
});
```

In my AccountController.cs

```
int accountNo = GenerateRandomNo();
var chk = db.sp_check_account_number(accountNo).ToList(); //check if there's redudancy in generated AccountNumber in Account Table
var cnt = chk.Count;
    if (cnt < 1)//If there is no redundancy
    {
        db.InsertNewAccount(name, accountNo);
    }
    else 
    {
        //if there's redundancy generate another account number
        while(cnt!=0)
        {
            accountNo = GenerateRandomNo();
            chk = db.GetROPAAccount(accountNo).ToList();
            cnt = chk.Count;
        }
        db.InsertNewAccount(name, accountNo); 
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
```

My insert method in `AccountController.cs` functioning well but the problem is when it's done inserting the data came from `$scope.accountList` array, the inserted `AccountNumber` in the table record got many redundancy. I found out that my `foreach loop` inserted the data randomly and I don't know why. I also check my `sp_check_account_number` and it's working fine. Can someone help me with this? :(

Comment: What does "got many redundancy" mean?

Comment: Can we see your code for `GenerateRandomNo()`?

Comment: Example I inserted 10 records, most of the account number inserted got duplicate or triplicate. And I don't know why it happen coz I got stored procedure `sp_check_account_number` that checks if there's a duplicate in generated account number

Comment: this is my code in `GenerateRandomNo()`
`public int GenerateRandomNo()
        {
            int min = 1000;
            int max = 9999;
            Random rdm = new Random();
            return rdm.Next(min, max);
        }`

Comment: There's your problem - `Random rdm = new Random();` - if that's called in rapid succession you often get the same seed value so the values aren't random. Move this line out as a class-level variable and try again. It'll work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is with the `GenerateRandomNo` method. Currently you have this:

```
public int GenerateRandomNo()
{
    int min = 1000;
    int max = 9999;
    Random rdm = new Random();
    return rdm.Next(min, max);
}
```

There's your problem - `Random rdm = new Random();` - if that's called in rapid succession you often get the same seed value so the values aren't random. Move this line out as a class-level variable and try again.

Do this:

```
private Random rdm = new Random();
public int GenerateRandomNo()
{
    int min = 1000;
    int max = 9999;
    return rdm.Next(min, max);
}
```

Also, as an extra thing, you're generating numbers from `1000` to `9998` when you use `1000` and `9999` as your input parameters. The second parameter is an **exclusive** maximum value.

Comment: You're a lifesaver Enigmativity. Thank you so much. But I wonder why my data in $scope.accountList array inserted in the database randomly

Comment: @VernonMaceda - What do you mean by "inserted in the database randomly"?

Comment: Coz I tested some records (e.g Test1, Test2, Test3...). In my `foreach loop` the data should be inserted base on its index but when the inserting of records was done, the records inserted not in order (e.g Test3, Test1, Test2).

Comment: @VernonMaceda - I don't know if there's a problem here. Databases don't have an order for records. If you want a display order you have to explicitly sort the data when you query it.